# Mysql en Ubuntu 18.04 Amazon Web Services

Tags: mysql, aws

Estoy aprendiendo acerca de VPS y cómo subir mis aplicaciones hechas con Laravel a estos.

Primero probé usando Digital Ocean y fue todo un éxito. Para mi segundo intento estoy usando Amazon Web Services y, mi principal problema tine que ver con las claves de acceso, ya que tengo que usar un archivo key en vez de simplemente usar contraseña para acceder como en Digital Ocean.
Mi problema actual es no poder ingresar a mysql, ya que no tengo idea cuál es mi contraseña de root, he probado dejar la contraseña en blanco y me dice "access denied for user root".

Probé hacer lo siguiente:

#sudo mysql_secure_installation

A lo cual el sistema me pide que ingrese una contraseña y no me da ningún error, pero luego vuelvo a hacer

#sudo mysql -u root -p

y a pesar de que introduzco esa nueva contraseña que establecí en el paso anterior, sigue dándome el mismo error de "access denied for user root".

Answer (score 1):

No sé cómo lo hice, pero lo solucioné.

Ejecuté esto:

```
#sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Como a la tercera vez de ejecutarlo y de re-iniciar el servicio mysql, finalmente me dejó logearme.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar resetear el password mysql/root.
Dentro de la terminal de AWS-Ubuntu...

1. cierra el servicio

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo killall mysqld
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

2. entra a la sesión de MySQL

```
mysql -u root
UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('EscribeTuNuevaContraseña') WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
```

3. inicia el servicio

```
sudo killall mysqld
sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: Mi problema es que no me deja logearme en mysql, y el paso 2 de re-establecer el password no me deja hacerlo ya que ni siquiera puedo entrar.